# Python3, my multiprocessing example not running parallel processes

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm new to multiprocessing. I've altered a simple example code, where a list is sent to worker subprocess, changed and sent back for printing. I've altered it in order to test if multiple processes are infact running in parallel and returned as each process finishes. The way I am testing this is by starting total[0],total[1],total[2],total[3] at the same time **but** forcing ONLY total[2] to pause before returning.

**The result:**

 total[0], total[1] print imminently. 
 total[2] waits (which it should) BUT total[3] also waits.

The output returns as follows:

> ```
> ['', 'DOCTYPE', 'HTML']
> ['LAST', 'NAV']
> ['TOPIC', 'FORUM']
> ['HEADLINE2', 'INNERHTML']
> ```

When I expected it to return like this:

> ```
> ['', 'DOCTYPE', 'HTML']
> ['LAST', 'NAV']
> ['HEADLINE2', 'INNERHTML']
> ['TOPIC', 'FORUM']
> ```

As I said, I'm quite new to subprocessing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**The code for my example**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time



def worker(inq,outq):
    obj = inq.get()
    for b in range(len(obj)):
        obj[b] = obj[b].upper()

    if obj[0] == 'TOPIC': time.sleep(9)
    outq.put(obj)


total = [['', 'doctype', 'html'], ['last', 'nav'], ['Topic', 'forum'], ['headline2', 'innerHTML']]

if __name__=='__main__':
    inq = []
    outq = []
    p = []
    for i in range(len(total)):
        inq.insert(i, mp.Queue())
        outq.insert(i, mp.Queue())

        p.insert(i, mp.Process(target=worker, args=(inq[i],outq[i])))
        p[i].start()

        inq[i].put(total[i])


    for i in range(len(total)):
        # Wait for the worker to finish
        p[i].join()

        result1 = outq[i].get()

        print(result1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your last `for` loop you are getting the results in order -- so, even though `3` finishes before `2`, you are getting `2`'s results first.

Try adding the line `print(obj)` to the end of `worker()` to see that `3` finishes first.

Comment: I will check this and get back to you as soon as I can. probably over the weekend